# Model methods work in Bookings model but not in Events and Tickets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app as my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

I am able to create model methods in Booking.rb and able to use them in my views. I am even able to pull data from other models in these methods. However, when I try to use model methods in Event and Ticket and try to use them in their show pages I get undefined method 'maximum_tickets_allowed'error (or whatever the method name is) when trying to print @event.event_fire or @ticket.maximum_tickets_allowed in the show pages. PFA the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yImwl.jpg

The Bookings Model:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
 belongs_to :ticket
 has_many :charges

def total_amount
    ticket.ticket_price.to_i * order_quantity.to_i
end

def test
    ticket.maximum_quantity.to_i
end
end
```

Bookings Show page:

```
 <h2>Booking Show</h2>

<p><%= @booking.buyer_name %></p>
<p><%= @booking.order_quantity %></p>
<p><%= @booking.ticket.ticket_name %></p>
<p><%= number_to_currency(@booking.total_amount) %></p>
<p><%= @booking.test %></p>
```

This renders fine. The problem arises in event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
has_many :bookings
has_many :charges

def self.event_fire
    self.about.upcase
    #ticket.maximum_quantity.to_i * ticket.minimum_quantity.to_i
end
end
```

Even simple calculations aren't recognized in the show template. When I use @event.event_fire to print the value. The same happens in the ticket model methods as well.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
 has_many :bookings

 def self.maximum_tickets_allowed
(1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
#max = maximum_quantity.to_i
#self.maximum_quantity = (1..max).to_a
#self.maximum_quantity = max
 end

end
```

The source code is here https://bitbucket.org/stravarius/ticket-fire. How do I get past this?

Comment: Where are the views that are creating issues for you ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :event
        has_many :bookings

        def maximum_tickets_allowed
            (1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
            #max = maximum_quantity.to_i
            #self.maximum_quantity = (1..max).to_a
            #self.maximum_quantity = max
        end

    end
```

remove `self` from `self.maximum_tickets_allowed`. Self is for class method. You cannot access a class method from instance methods. Check more http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/